# prevent get_comments() from returning comments not in comment__in

Tags: wp-query, comments, wp-comment-query

The query string comment__in takes an array of comment IDs to include. I have an array of comment IDs that I would like to assign to  `comment__in`, such as `$args['comment__in'] = $comment_IDs;`. Some comment IDs in `$comment_IDs` do not exists in the database and some do. Regardless, when a comment ID exists in the database, it gets returned by `get_comments($args)`. However when none of the comments IDs in `$comment_IDs` exist in the database, `get_comments($args)` returns a large number of comments that are not in `$comment_IDs`

**The question is:**
How can I get `get_comments($args)` to only return comments specified by `$comment_IDs`?

Comment: That shouldn't happen unless the query args or comments/results are filtered by a plugin or some custom code. So have you tried using static values, e.g. `get_comments( [ 'comment__in' => [ 1, 2, 3 ] ] )`  where the comments with the ID 1/2/3 did not actually exist? And did you check if the `$comment_IDs` actually contained valid IDs/integers?

Comment: I used an array of integers. Each integer represents a comment ID, but some IDs do not exist in the database anymore.

Comment: The correct comments are being returned when there is atleast one comment ID in the array, but the problem occurs when the array of comment IDs is empty. Checking if $comment_IDs is empty before using it not a solution either

Comment: Well, if it's an empty array, then it means `comment__in` would also be empty, which is the same as not specifying that arg, so if that's the case, then of course all comments (that matched the other args) would be returned. And why would checking if the `$comment_IDs` array is empty or not, is not a solution? I mean, you could do something like `if ( ! empty( $comment_IDs ) ) { get_comments( [ 'comment__in' => $comment_IDs ] ); }`, no? Or am I not understanding you?

Comment: Checking if `$comment_IDs` is empty might actually work. I will need to test it out. Adding a -1 to the array also works